Sorting the data in mongodb
I have a field in mongodb called propertyRating the values are 5.0/4.0/3.0/SC.
I want to sort the data based on propertyRating,
first 5 star then 4 star,3 star and in last SC.
Is there any way to sort the data by 5,4,3 and then SC.
I used,
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [$match] => Array
                (
                    [total_charges] => Array
                        (
                            [$gt] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [$sort] => Array
                (
                    [propertyRating] => -1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [$skip] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [$limit] => 20
        )

)

Which sorts the SC value data first then 5,4,3 star data.

This is the expected behaviour. Strings are having larger sort order than numbers, so they are always larger than numbers. You need to map the strings to some values less than 3 to achieve your expected sorting order,

Hey @ray
Thanks for the answer.

As ray suggested, "You need to map the strings to some values less than 3". So create a field for sorting on and set the value to something appropriate like -1.0 when the value is "SC".
Here's an aggregation pipeline to do that:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // set `propertyRatingSort` to -1.0 when it's "SC"
    // otherwise use the value as-is
    $set: {
      propertyRatingSort: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$propertyRating", "SC"] },
          -1.0,
          "$propertyRating"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // sort descending using the created sort field
  { $sort: { propertyRatingSort: -1 } },
  // remove the extra field
  { $unset: "propertyRatingSort" }
])

Mongo Playground
Put your $match total_charges > 0 stage before the first $set above.

Hey @aneroid
Thank you so much for the detail explaination.
I applied the logic and it worked.
